# Search token color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tokenize

I am using `bootstrap` search `field+tokeninput`.

I am trying to get tokens of different colors, and to add the `id` to each token.

I am using this bootstrap search field:

```
<input type="text" id="exampleInlineTags" class="token-field" name="search" value="red, green" placeholder="enter text" />
```

and boostrap tokeninput [See the source for bootstrap-tokenfield](https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield)
, everything is working fine, now I need to set predefined colors on token input, just like this: [Example of what I am trying to achieve](http://pokit.org/get/?549adc16cc5d48a1052da6d7e379f8e0.jpg)

EDIT : Corrected the grammar of the question as OP mentioned having a bad level of English

Comment: How about this suggestion?
https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield/issues/94

Comment: nothing happend, when i use this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a specific id and color assigned based on the value of the token then you could listen for the tokenfield:createtoken event.

However if you need to just cycle colors for the tokens I suggest you use the CSS to achieve your goal. For cycling a pattern of 10 colors you could write:

```
.token:nth-of-type(10n+1){ ... }

.token:nth-of-type(10n+2){ ... }

...

.token:nth-of-type(10n+10){ ... }
```